# Is it possible to introduce method responses in JUnit tests?

Tags: junit

Is it possible to ‘feed’ expected responses from underlying methods to classes under test in JUnit? Of course, you can splatter the code with `if`-statements doing something else in case the code is “under test” or introduce an extra bag of objects either forwarding a request to an object (normal obperation) or doing that “something else”, but it leaves a feeling of smelly code and extra bugs. Is there a better approach to keep test code really out of the program code?

I imagine something like *if `ClassUnderTest.doSomething()` calls `ClassB.getValue(key)` don’t call that function at all, instead, hand value `foo` as an imaginary return value of `ClassB.getValue()` back to `ClassUnderTest.doSomething()`*? Can that be done some way? Can I access “key” later to see if my method posed the right question? (See: I don’t want to test the functionality of `ClassB` here, just the `doSomething()̀  method itself.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for are mocking frameworks.

The most popular these days seems to be [Mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/).